# Collapse with label in stata

Tags: stata

I want to keep my variable labels after collapsing in stata. I found Nick Cox's solution not working for me. The code looks like this:
Before -collapse-, copy the variable labels to local macros:

```
foreach v of var * { 
    local l`v' : variable label `v' 
}
```

After -collapse-, use the old labels:

```
foreach v of var * { 
    label var `v' "`l`v''" 
}
```

All my variables after collapsing still have no labels.

Comment: please accept the answer, as the syntax does what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

[This post](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/keeping-same-variable-with-collapse/) extensively tackles the problem, but:

before collapse you need:

```
foreach v of var * {
 local l`v' : variable label `v'
       if `"`l`v''"' == "" {
    local l`v' "`v'"
    }
}
```

after collapse you need:

```
foreach v of var * {
label var `v' "`l`v''"
}
```

Comment: I mentioned explicitly that this code does not work for me.

Comment: because the chunk in your question does not correspond to what Nick Cox wrote and I quoted here.